# How can I handle ASP request in an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, asp-classic

I have a site which is hosted in ASP.NET environment. The site is currently able to handle .aspx request. If a user request a .aspx page which does not exist in the server, then I can redirect him/her to a generic error page.

Now the problem is if a user make a request for .asp page, 
for example if a user types

**http://wwww.example.com/index.asp**

Then the error handler does not work. I want to redirect him/her here,

**http://wwww.example.com/index.aspx**

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For a [permanent redirect](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)

```
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.new-url.com/"
```

OR [this](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641)

```
Response.Redirect "http://www.new-url.com/"
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I have edited the question. Can you please answer again?